# How to set empty value?

Tags: java

My problem is that I don't know how to set empty value. Because first 3 values must be empty.

I tried to set `NaN` or just didn't print value then it does not pass the test.
So, how I set empty value? It is possible or I just don't understand my assignment?

It's an assignment for Weighted Moving Average.
It's must look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kziab.png) but as I said I don't know how to print empty value.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And i forgot. It's double value.

Comment: Hey, you should give more context:
1. What are you trying to write
2. What have you tried
3. How did it fail

It's also a good idea to copy&paste your code

Comment: Please, attach the code you are working on in the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you call empty depends on your problem. In Java, empty values are usually reflected as `null`. The problem is that you cannot use nulls with primitive types such as `double`. You probably want to use a wrapper type, `java.lang.Double` in your case.

For example :

```
Double emptyValue = null;
```